# How to filter rows when reading csv file

Tags: python, csv, filtering

I would like to browse data in CSV format. For that I use this:

```
with open("file.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        print row`
```

Output:

```
Prenom  Nom   Profession
Djef    Pink  Cascadeur
Win     Red   Actor
Max     Blue  Prof
DEEN    Red   fisherman
```

With this piece of code I can display my table and also a specific column.
But I would like to provide, for example, displaying all the columns with as a condition all the elements of the second column which are equal to RED:

```
Prenom  Nom  Profession
Win     Red  Actor
DEEN    Red  fisherman
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas to deal with tables in Python.

Let's recreate your file:

```
import io

data = """\
Prenom;Nom;Profession
Djef;Pink;Cascadeur
Win;Red;Actor
Max;Blue;Prof
DEEN;Red;fisherman"""

file = io.StringIO(data)
```

Now to the actual code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=";") #change file to filepath
output = df[df.Nom == 'Red'].to_csv(sep='\t',index=False)
print(output)
```

Prints:

```
Prenom  Nom    Profession
Win     Red    Actor
DEEN    Red    fisherman
```

Comment: Thank you for your  answer.

Answer (score 0):

The row you read is a 0 based array of strings.

```
with open("file.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        if row[1]=="RED":
            print row
```

**NOT TESTED**